# Two rows with different sizes in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have a Navbar in Bootstrap that looks like

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                               press | login | ... | <-second nav with smaller 
+---------------------------------------------------+   height, text, ...
|   LO   |       |     |     |                      |
|   GO   |  HOME | FOO | BAR |                      | <-main menu with normal
+---------------------------------------------------+   height and text
```

Is there something like `navbar-small` in Bootstrap? Has someone any other hints how to do this with Bootstrap?

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div id="second-nav" class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">press</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FOO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BAR</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

I want to have `#second-nav` smaller.

Comment: You can adjust the height of the navbar.

Comment: just in an own css-file?

Comment: Any live example of what you are trying to achieve? Yes, in a custom CSS file.

Comment: I added my HTML to the Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your top navbar, the padding on the anchor elements is increasing the height. You can remove it using the following code. Output in Full screen.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #second-nav li a {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div id="second-nav" class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">press</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">login</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">...</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Beratungsansatz<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FOO</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">BAR</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have in one of my application to adjust both the size of the font and the height of the navbar

```
.navbar-nav {
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 1.428;
}
```

You can adjust depending on what you mean by "small" and "normal"

Depending on how you structured the nav bar in your template/views you just call the class in the appropriate tag. This is an example with a ul list tag

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <!-- your links -->
  </ul>
```

Comment: but I have 2 `.navbar-nav` and don't want to change both ;-) I know I can do it with an ID, but I was looking for Bootstraps built-in-possibility

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need dude

```css
#second-nav li a {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
#second-nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
div#second-nav {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div id="second-nav" class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">press</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">login</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">...</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Beratungsansatz<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FOO</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">BAR</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nupxw75u/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I know you have an answer but this might be helpful anyways and takes the mobile viewport into consideration.

```css
.navbar-default.nav-top ul {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.navbar-default ul.navbar-top li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar-default nav-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-top">
      <li><a href="#">press</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">login</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">.....</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x25/f00/f00">
      </a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Foo</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Bar</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```